# VmWare - Internet connection not available in Virtual machine

Tags: networking, vmware, virtualization

I'm using VMWare. My host machine has internet connection. I have selected NAT in the virtual machine settings. What else do I need to do to get internet connection in virtual machine.

Comment: Is there any specific services to run in Host for NAT to work?

Comment: What is your host OS?

Comment: VMWare's installer had created two virtual network adapters. but,i had disabled them.how to get it back?

Comment: After selecting NAT you still need to share your host network to your NAT VMnet. You can do that from Network and Sharing Center. Follow steps from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2j3nyl4muQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know your situation, but try a bridged connection.

Comment: i have better solution, see my answer https://superuser.com/a/1271869/128448

Answer (score 3):

To get the Internet connection working on the Virtual Machine:

1. Click **VM** from menu bar
2. Click **Setting**
3. Click **Network Adapter**
4. In *Network Connection* choose **Custom:Specific virtual network** and then choose **VMnet0 (auto bridging)**

Comment: Someone commented in a (hopefully) deleted answer that this also worked after upgrading Windows 8 to 10.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'm assuming you're talking about VMWare Workstation or VMWare Player, and not VMWare Server (free edition.)

In response to your 'any specific services to run in Host for NAT to work?' addition to the question, yes, there are services directly related to NAT.  You should have a VMWare NAT and VMWare DHCP service.  Both must be running for NAT to work properly.  I may be wrong, but I believe the VMWare Authorization Service must be running as well.

Also, make sure your guest's network settings are set to use DHCP.  When you have the VM configured to use NAT, VMWare will answer the DHCP request.  If you have your VM configured to use a bridged connection, you must have a DHCP server on your *real* local network that will give the guest an IP.

One last thing, VMWare's installer will have created two virtual network adapters.  Make sure you haven't disabled them. Your guest 'reaches' through these.

Ok, ONE last thing: Remember that a NAT'd VM will appear, to the rest of the world, as your host machine.  A bridged VM will appear as a true host to the rest of the world.  Depending on your network environment, this can cause issues. For example, here at work, the network is configured such that a MAC address is tied to a network port in the wall.  ie: I can not unplug my desktop from the wall and connect my laptop, nor can I plug my desktop into a different network port.  As such, I can not use bridged VMs. Because a bridged VM appears as a true host on the network with it's own MAC address, my bridged VMs packets are denied at the switch.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to use diagnostic on connection  in windows (in WM). It is solves problem by it self. It helped me in my case.

Comment: Funny enough, I had a VM that suddenly lost internet, and that absolutely *didn't* fix it - threw a weird error. Then I set it to connect using "Custom:"->"VMnet0" like the upvoted answer above, and that didn't work either. Then after setting it to use VMnet0, I ran the diagnostic wizard a second time, and then it worked. Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

Nat sometimes comes up with weird results.

Try Bridged connection and if you have a DHCP server, it should automatically assign a DHCP lease and you should have an active internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get an internet connection via NAT or bridged.  Have you installed VMWare Tools in your VM?  I usually can't get any connection until I do.

Comment: Yes I have installed VMWare tools

Answer (score 0):

You need to have both adapters enabled in VMware
If you want to create a network one should be set on the team and one on NAT with the host

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Windows 8 on virtual PC and enabled NAT Connection. All fine, but i had no Internet connection. All possible solutions tested, but not luck. After this i have looked in my network state and it looks like so:

[image]

DNS-Server address was wrong! I have opened my network settings in changed DNS-Server address from auto to manual, entered IP-Address from my Router and woops, it work's.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem with my linux virtual machines over vmware, using NAT.

The soluction was, in the networks connections of Windows ( conection Vnet8 ), right button --> Diagnose.
Regards,